# exit function if 0 is entered at any time for any variable

Tags: python, variables, exit

```
def function():
   restart = 'yes'
   while restart == 'yes':
       **long program here**
       restart = input("would you like to restart?: ")
```

In the /long program/ section, i have many variables and it would be crazy to put an 'if' statement on each if the user wants to exit the function, so is there a way that whenever prompted to enter for a variable, if the user enters 0 the program exits the function?

thanks

Comment: well, there's no good answer to your question, as your issue is a software design one, not a programmatic question. Because it might be indeed insane to have 42 ifs after each query, but what's even more insane is to have a *long algorithm* in a while block. You should consider to split your lengthy algorithm into multiple small ones, and on each return of your subroutines, have a value that when set, breaks out of the loop. Think in terms of state automaton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 2-arg form of `iter` - providing it a sentinel value where the loop stops, eg:

```
def function():
    for value in iter(lambda: input('would you like to restart?:'), '0'):
        pass # do your stuff here
    return None # or some meaningful result here
```

nb: use `raw_input` if using Python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Just use a helper function to check if a variable has an "exit" value,  and if yes exit the the whole program (or throw an exception and catch it and exit).

For example (pseudo-code):

```
def check_exit(var, exit):
  if var == 0: 
    exit()
    return
  return var
```

The function accepts a variable "var" and a function to call on exit, so you can pass a custom exit function to do what you need

A similar alternative (variation) is to check all variables at once (once they have been inserted by the user) and exit if anyone has an "exit value". Then this check code or function could be at the end of your other code and called only once for all variables. As metnioned in comments this is a design issue and not a specific python programmatic issue per se

Comment: that's the answer I gave before deleting it: the OP wants to ~exit~ return from *a function*, not exit a program.

Comment: your return is redundant

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, i know but good to be there anyway, since it depends on what the exit function will do

Comment: @zmo, well in that case i would suggest to leave the OP decide what answer to accept on what grounds

Comment: If the OP wants to quit the function just return but that still won't kill the main loop.

Answer (score -1):

So you want something like my snippet below, but for exiting a function. Sadly that's not possible. What you need is to reconsider your algorithm so you split it in multiple subroutines, that gets checked when getting back in the while block, and either breaks out of the loop to exit the function or keep it flowing.

---

First answer:

well, if I do understand your question correctly, you want to make it possible to exit the program whenever you ask the user for input, when the user enters a 0. If I did understand correctly, you could do something like that:

```
def exit_if_zero(val):
    if val.strip() == "0":
        sys.exit(0)
    return val
```

which returns the value that gets entered, but if the user gives a `0`, it will exit. So you could use it the following way:

```
value = exit_if_zero(input("enter a value"))
```

HTH

Comment: this is the same as my answer

Comment: if you did not downvote my answer i can remove ther downvote from this answer and let the OP decide, fair?

Comment: tried to (dummy) edit (some hours ago) the answer to remove downvote, but edit was rejected, if it is edited, can remove the downvote